# Spring Batch PartitionStep get UNKNOWN or stay in STARTED state for a long time (hours)

Tags: spring-batch, weblogic

Partition steps reading data from DB in multiple threads. step execution managing by WorkManager in WebLogic. And from time to time it gets stucked (in state STARTED or STARTING for hours) or gets state UNKNOWN due to unable to update rollback (obtain db connection). Does spring batch have any mechanism which will help to prevent those situations?

Stopping by JobOperator.stop() job with partiotion steps which get stuck doesnt help in this case. It updates job state, but partition step still STARTED or STARTING and after that I cant restart JOB bacause steps were not stopped.

Answer (score 0):

This means the worker step that was processing that particular partition was not stopped gracefully.

In this case, you need to set the `end_time` to a non null value and status of the corresponding step execution to `FAILED` and restart the job. Only failed partitions will be replayed.